# How do I start emacs with two horizontal windows one of which is dired?

Tags: dired, window, window-splitting

How do I write a function and call it in my init script so that when I open a file, I have two horizontal windows, the left one being dired mode and about 25% of the total emacs screen, while the other window takes up 75%?

Comment: Maybe you could explain why you want this. As there might be better alternatives available already, like e.g. [treemacs](https://github.com/Alexander-Miller/treemacs), you could make a shortcut for toggling it. Otherwise, if you really prefer to have such function, then you should explain what to do with other windows that might exist when you open that file.

Comment: So kind of an emacs newbie. Basically when I open up a file for programming, I want to have a file navigator available on the left side along with the file i am working on.

Comment: Another possibility is `speedbar` which is distributed with emacs.

Comment: treemacs comes with prelude, which is what I use. That serves my purposes well.